# Error in LogCat while developing a barcode scanner for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, zxing, android-logcat

I followed the steps provided in the Zxing project. I have created a single button to scan a barcode. I am using emulator in Eclipse and I am having a webcam(according to the suggestion of @Sean Owen) which would do the image capture for me. While running the project after I click the scan button a prompt's asking whether I want to install an existing separate app named Barcode Scanner which is needed to begin the scan process. So, as soon as I choose the yes option the project crashes and shows that the application stopped working. Also I am having the following error in LogCat. Any help would be appreciated.

[image: This error is showing inside LogCat while running my android project]

Comment: make sure you have Google play installed on emulator

Comment: No, I don't have Google Play installed on the emulator. Do I need to install?

Comment: Yes, you need it. Or you can just pull BarcodeScanner*.apk from googlecode and push it to your emulator using `adb install`.

Comment: Is there a way to install a .apk file to the emulator from local hard drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its simple I guess. You don't have the Google Play app installed on your device. Either try to install it or find a device which has one installed.

Comment: Is there a way to install a .apk file to the emulator from local hard drive? @Andro Selva

Comment: I have tried this earlier. But I was not successful in it. I have seen some forums which tells you how to do it. But I am not sure how far they could be helpful.

Comment: Okay. I guess you have worked on emulator. So, my question is did you have the emulator which have Google play pre-installed? If not how have you managed development?

Comment: I used a device since emulator was not suitable for this purpose.

Comment: Okay. So, it is evident that my project can not be tested on emulator.

Answer (score 2):

You do not have the app that can handle the intent for barcode  scanner.Go to the Google Play app and install one barcode scanner.Check if the issue persists